# How to write a character "x" number of times

Tags: batch-file, repeat

I am trying to create a batch file that uses user input to create the following..

1. How many records to create
2. Name of filename to save text file as
3. What character to use
4. How many times to repeat character in option 3

I am a self taught novice at batch making but I do understand some....
the following is what I have, I know it is not correct and maybe it is just backwards...I probably need to set what to write, how many times to repeat on one line in the text, then repeat steps for the amount of records in a file.
The end result will look something like the following:

```
0000000000  0000  000000000
0000000000  0000  000000000
```

etc etc for the amount of total records by user input...
%column1bytecount%  %column2bytecount%  %column3bytecount% REPEAT THIS %howmanyrecords%

The following does not work. (I have to be close)

```
@Echo Off

Set /P howmanyrecords=How Many Records Would You Like To Produce: 
set /P savefilename=Please Type Name Of Sample Pin File To Save: 
Set /P charactertowrite=What Character Would You Like To Use (typically 0 is used): 
Set /P Column1bytecount=How Many Bytes In Column 1: 


for /L %%A in (1,1,%howmanyrecords%) do (
echo 0000000000  0000  00000000 >> %savefilename%
```

)

Comment: "does not work" is not a meaningful problem description. In what way does it "not work" specifically? Does it give you the wrong output? Does it simply not execute? Does it end up with invalid input? Please be specific about the problem you're having with the code you posted - "does not work" won't do.

Comment: I have updated my code to something that does work.  
This will repeat the ECHO however many times from user input of %howmanyrecords% 

What I would like to figure out is how to replace the 

Echo 00000000000  0000  00000000 >> %savefilename%

To user input.

Comment: I have updated my code to something that does work.  
This will repeat the ECHO however many times from user input of %howmanyrecords% 

What I would like to figure out is how to replace the 

Echo 00000000000  0000  00000000 >> %savefilename%

To user input.

How would I go about coding 
Echo %charactertowrite% ->> %column1bytecount% (on one line) repeated %howmanyrecords%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

Set /P howmanyrecords=How Many Records Would You Like To Produce: 
set /P savefilename=Please Type Name Of Sample Pin File To Save: 
Set /P charactertowrite=What Character Would You Like To Use (typically 0 is used): 
Set /P Columnbytecount=How Many Bytes In Columns (separate by commas) : 

SET "line="
CALL :setline %columnbytecount%

for /l %%i in (1,1,%howmanyrecords%) do (
 >>%savefilename% echo %line%
)

GOTO :EOF

:setline
SET "thiscolumn=%1"
IF NOT DEFINED thiscolumn SET "line=%line:~0,-2%"&GOTO :EOF 
:buildloop
SET "line=%line%%charactertowrite%"
SET /a thiscolumn-=1
IF %thiscolumn% neq 0 GOTO buildloop
:: add separator - 2 spaces (not specified)
SET "line=%line%  "
SHIFT
GOTO setline
```

This should get the job done.

I've slightly changed the spec. You can enter the columns as a series of digits, separated by commas (or spaces). For your example, you'd enter `10,4,9` for instance.

The process builds the output line in `line`, then writes the line the required number of times. Note that you can't put a label within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements)

The `setline` subroutine accepts the parameterlist specified as `columnbytecount`. It puts the first parameter into `thiscolumn` and adds the specified character to `line` that number of times. When the count reaches zero, it adds two spaces (you don't specify what the spacing is, but it looks like two spaces) and `shifts` the parameter list so that the original second parameter becomes first.

Repeat that operation until the parameter list is exhaused, then remove the last two characters (as two spaces have been added when the last column finished) end exit from the subroutine by reaching end-of-file.

The substring syntax is

```
%var:~start,length% if start >=0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start >=0 and endpos <0
%var:~start,length% if start <0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start <0 and endpos <0
```

- length/endpos may be omitted. If omitted, the substring is "from the start position to the end"
- `%` may be `!` for `delayedexpansion` mode

Comment: WOW, Thank you Magoo it is exactly what I wanted the final product to be...and yes it is 2 spaces.  You saved me lots of time by giving final product, now I can play around with your batch and try to learn some more.   Again THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you're wanting to do.

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set /P "howmanyrecords=How Many Records Would You Like To Produce: "
Set /P "savefilename=Please Type Name Of Sample Pin File To Save: "
Set /P "charactertowrite=What Character Would You Like To Use (typically 0 is used): "
Set /P "column1bytecount=How Many Bytes In Column 1: "

for /l %%i in (1,1,%howmanyrecords%) do (
    set line=
    for /l %%j in (1,1,%column1bytecount%) do (
        set line=!line!!charactertowrite!
    )

    echo !line!>> !savefilename!
)
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, I upped the rep because your code was helpful, I probably would have figured out the rest of it based off your code, however Magoo's answer below went basically to the end of what I wanted finished product to be.  THANK YOU though for the response!

Comment: No problem, Magoos answer was significantly better than mine.